# Multiplyiing array values based on same keys

Tags: php

Let's say i have two array like this:

```
Array1 ( [scholarshipId] => 8 [studentId] => 2571 [weightage] => ["20","20","20"] )
```

and another one is:

```
Array2 ( [0] => Array ( [weightage] => ["60","20","20"] ) )
```

Now i want multiply the values of `weightage` and then calculate total sum.

Please help me out.

Comment: @TomUdding this will not give `1602`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we are gathering product of values in an array `$result` and then finally adding those array values with function `array_sum`

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/780389)

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$array1 = Array(
    "scholarshipId" => 8,
    "studentId" => 2571,
    "weightage" => ["20", "20", "20"]
     );
$array2 = Array(
           0 => Array(
                "weightage" => ["60", "20", "20"]
               )
         );

$result=array();
foreach($array1["weightage"] as $key => $value)
{
    $result[]=$value*$array2[0]["weightage"][$key];
}

print_r(array_sum($result));
```

Comment: Gulatiji array1 and array2 are dynamic arrays. However i tried your code snippet but giving Invalid argument supplied for foreach().

Comment: I tried like this  :  ini_set('display_errors', 1);
   $array1 = $evaldata;
   $array2 = $multi;

   $result=array();
   foreach($array1["weightage"] as $key => $value)
   {
    $result[]=$value*$array2[0]["weightage"][$key];
   }

   print_r(array_sum($result));
   exit;

Answer (score 0):

```
$value = $array1['weightage'][0] * $array2['weightage'][0];
$value2 = $array1['weightage'][1] * $array2['weightage'][1];
$value3 = $array1['weightage'][2] * $array2['weightage'][2];
$sum = $value + $value2 + $value3
```

Something like that?